# CAST(col AS DATE) on a DATETIME field in TeraData doesn't clip the time portion

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column that's defined as a DATETIME field, and always has the time set to 12:00:00 AM.  I want to return JUST the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Everything I've read suggests that `CAST(colName AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')` is all I should need to do, but my returned values remain in the `dd/mm/yyyy 12:00:00 AM` format it's stored in.

What am I missing?

Comment: because I'm not in charge of the DB creation, I'm just a lowly user :(

Comment: `CAST(timestampcol AS DATE)` is correct, it trims the time portion. The display format is probably defined by your client. Btw, there's no DATETIME in Teradata, just DATE, TIMESTAMP and TIME.